# Code::Blocks debugger doesn't work with functions

Tags: gdb

I have the installed Code::Blocks version "codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe" and tried to debug a function x. Couple of seconds later after I have putted "x(3)" into watches, the debugger closes. I also tried to reinstall it a couple of times, but it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x(int y)
{
    return y * 3;
}

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

This is the log file provided by the debugger

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: D:\CP\dddd\
Adding source dir: D:\CP\dddd\
Adding file: D:\CP\dddd\bin\Debug\dddd.exe
Changing directory to: D:/CP/dddd/.
Set variable: PATH=.;D:\Applications\CB\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;D:\Applications\CB\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Applications\Intel Management\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;D:\Applications\Intel Management\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Users\Sochu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

[debug]Command-line: D:\Applications\CB\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args D:/CP/dddd/bin/Debug/dddd.exe
[debug]Working dir : D:\CP\dddd

Starting debugger: D:\Applications\CB\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args D:/CP/dddd/bin/Debug/dddd.exe
done

[debug]Reading symbols from D:/CP/dddd/bin/Debug/dddd.exe...
[debug]done.
[debug](gdb) 
[debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:

Setting breakpoints

[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> show version
[debug]GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
[debug]Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[debug]License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[debug]This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
[debug]There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
[debug]and "show warranty" for details.
[debug]This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
[debug]Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
[debug]For bug reporting instructions, please see:
[debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[debug]Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
[debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
[debug]For help, type "help".
[debug]Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set confirm off

Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1

[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set width 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set height 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set breakpoint pending on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print asm-demangle on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set unwindonsignal on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print elements 200
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set new-console on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set disassembly-flavor att
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> catch throw
[debug]Catchpoint 1 (throw)
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> directory D:/CP/dddd/
[debug]Source directories searched: D:/CP/dddd;$cdir;$cwd
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> tbreak "D:/CP/dddd/main.cpp:11"
[debug]Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x40156f: file D:\CP\dddd\main.cpp, line 11.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> run
[debug]Starting program: D:\CP\dddd\bin\Debug\dddd.exe 

Child process PID: 14020

[debug][New Thread 14020.0x3298]
[debug][New Thread 14020.0x458]
[debug][New Thread 14020.0x1f94]
[debug][New Thread 14020.0x316c]
[debug]Thread 1 hit Temporary breakpoint 2, main () at D:\CP\dddd\main.cpp:12
[debug]D:\CP\dddd\main.cpp:12:103:beg:0x40156f
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

At D:\CP\dddd\main.cpp:12

[debug]> show language
[debug]The current source language is "auto; currently c++".
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> info locals
[debug]No locals.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> info args
[debug]No arguments.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> whatis x(3)
[debug]type = int
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> output x(3)

Debugger finished with status 1
```

Comment: gdb 8.1 had a [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22854) when you tried to call any function. It's fixed since 8.2, so you need to update to a newer version.

Comment: Could you tell me how to update it? I don't find any updated tutorials.

Comment: Since this bug is now a few years old, I'm surprised they never updated gdb in Code::Blocks, there even is an [open ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/1020/).